# Does shapefile automatically save across computers?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile

My colleague and I are working on a project.  I have a shapefile that I edit every time.  Let's say they are address points. so I edit and save them.

My colleague opens up the different mxd on her computer but has the same shapefile sourced to it in the ToC.  will that shapefile edits automatically show up without her having to do anything?

Comment: Well, yes, except when she opens first, then you might get locked out, or the shapefile might get completely trashed...

Comment: When you say "same" you are referring to the same file that is stored on a shared network drive and both users have that file used from the same location in their project? Because if you store the files locally on the hard drive of the computer obviously they will not be syncronized.

Comment: If you are are both editing the same file (i.e. using a network storage drive that you both have access to), then yes.  If you have one copy of the file on your computer and she has a copy on her computer, then no.

Comment: If you're both *editing* the same data, then this is a hard no. If you're only *adding* features, that won't cause read failures too often (it could cause spatial indexes to "miss" some features). Actually editing geometry (changing vertex count) will cause some features to be marked for deletion and churn in the `.shp`,`.shx`,`.dbf`, as well as `.sbn`/`.sbx` and other indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, multiuser viewing of shapefiles is possible.

A few help docs.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/about-editing-shapefiles.htm

https://community.esri.com/t5/data-management-questions/is-multi-user-editing-on-the-same-shapefile/td-p/698573